# login wordpress issue : Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, wordpress, hosting

I'm trying to login to my site but I get this error

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'edwardl_wp1user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home1/edwardl8/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1568

Here is line 1568:

```
$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this 
>dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
 } else {
$this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, 
$this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
}
```

I wrote my passwords correctly, but it's still not working.

Comment: Is there something missing between `$this` and `>dbpassword` on the first line of your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database prefix is correct in your wp-config.php . Sometimes that triggerss such an error.